# Using Tweepy: TypeError: get_user() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, tweepy

```
api = tweepy.API(auth) 

# using get_user with id
_id = "103770785"
user = api.get_user(_id)

# printing the name of the user
print("The id " + _id + " corresponds to the user with the name : " + user.name)
```

That is my code. I can't find the solution for this message: `TypeError: get_user() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Comment: Change `user = api.get_user(_id)` to `user = api.get_user(user_id=_id)`

Answer (score 0):

[`API.get_user`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#tweepy.API.get_user) doesn't accept any positional arguments.
The one being referred to in the error is `self`.
You'll want to pass `_id` as the `user_id` kwarg.
See the [relevant FAQ section in Tweepy's documentation](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.6.0/faq.html#why-am-i-getting-a-typeerror-about-an-api-method-taking-1-positional-argument-but-given-2).

Comment: copying the documentation without explaining it is useless.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34819502)

Comment: @G.Lebret Not if the documentation answers the question, but sure, that's why I explained the documentation that I wrote in this answer.

Comment: @Itération122442 The linked page will not change as it's a specific version of the documentation. Regardless, it's already as you're saying it should be. The answer is complete without the link, and the link simply serves as reference for the answer.